# How to get only the root and leaf in a hierarchical self-referencing structure (SQL Alchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am wondering if it is possible in a self-referencing hierarchical structure to get all "roots", meaning elements without parents, and all their furthest descendants or "leaf" elements.

So if I have a table model like this:

```
class Model(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'model'

    # Columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('model.id'), nullable=True)
```

I can get all descendants of a single root like this:

```
s = session()
beginning_getter = s.query(Model).filter(Model.id == id).cte(name='children_for', recursive=True)
with_recursive = beginning_getter.union_all(s.query(Model).filter(Model.parent_id == beginning_getter.c.id))
return s.query(with_recursive)
```

where id is the primary key of a root parent.

I can get all root parents like this:

```
top_levels: List[Model] = s.query(Model).where(Model.parent_id == None).all()
```

But is there a way to only get the leaf (or all root/leaf pairs)? And how do I do it for all the parents at the same time?

Comment: Is this essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023808/get-all-descendants-of-all-parents-with-sql-alchemy?

Comment: I don't know if its in bad form to post 2 very similar questions, but they are different. I would like a function that gets all roots with all descendants, and one that gets all roots with only their last descendant. I did not want to ask both in the same question, but maybe I should have if they are too similar. @IljaEverilä

Comment: I see, I just failed to parse the question properly at first. While the latter can use parts of the former, sounds like the cases require slightly different approaches. To find leafs, find the set of nodes that do not have child nodes. If you keep passing the root ID along, you're done. To find that set you first need the set of all descendants (from the other question).

Comment: You can of course also find the leafs directly (using the same idea, find the set with no children), and then work your way up the trees to find the roots.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66886066/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson The answer in that post shows it for one root. I want to find some way of getting the trees of all the roots (that is, models without any parent). All examples I have seen they find the tree of one parent, but my use case is I have to do it for a lot of parents at once, and I don't think it will be viable to simply loop through the parents and perform the query, as it will take way too long.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That is true, and that could be an acceptable solution for me, if I could only find a way to do it for a collection of roots it would be fine, but all examples I have seen are in regards to a single parent.